# How to reset CreateCanvas() in JS after being called

Tags: javascript, p5.js

When I was writing the code I saw that the code would not reset the canvas to `(400, 400)` after being changed to `(600, 600)`. **It would disorientate the canvas and stretch all the shapes with it in** `evaporation()`. When going through all the screens and trying to go back to reset back.

```js
//Variables
let screen = 0;
let bugs = [];
let amt = 1000;
let xpos=0;


function setup() {
  
  colorMode(HSB);
  //Changes Colormode to HSB(Hue-Saturation-Brightness)

  //Creates the particles for the evaporation screen
  //For loop with increasement that states more of the smoke is created
  for (let i = 0; i < amt; i++) {
    let x = 200;
    let y = 300;
    let rad = random(10, 50);

    let b = new Bug(x, y, rad);
    bugs[i] = b;
  }
}

//Says if the value of screen changes so does the screen
function draw() {
  if(screen == 0) {
    evaporationscreen();
  } else if(screen == 1) {
    condensation();
  } else if(screen == 2) {
    presipitation();
  }
}

//Evaporation
function evaporationscreen() {
  background('#d2b48c'); 
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  //NOT RGB, HSB COLOR PALLETE(DO NOT MIX UP);
  
  //HTML Color pallete('e928320');

  noStroke();
  fill('#3895d3') //Lake
  circle(400, 400, 600)
  fill('#18bdf0') //Sky
  rect(0, 0, 400, 200);
  fill('#ffff00');  //Sun
  circle(300, 60, 70);
  fill('#e9bd15'); //Darkspots on Sun
  circle(315, 75, 10);//Forms the Sun and Darkspots
  circle(280, 52, 8);//Forms the Sun and Darkspots
  circle(299, 60, 13);//Forms the Sun and Darkspots
  circle(320, 48, 9);//Forms the Sun and Darkspots
  circle(295, 30, 6);//Forms the Sun and Darkspots
  circle(284, 79, 9);//Forms the Sun and Darkspots
  fill(240, 100, 50);//Forms the Sun and Darkspots
  rect(0, 200, 400, 400); //Beach
  
  console.log("EVAPORATION");
  
  //Lots of variables
  let stoprip = 45;
  let lake = int(dist(400, 400, mouseX, mouseY));
  var starx = random(0, 400);
  var stary = random (10, 190);
  var sun = int(dist(300, 60, mouseX, mouseY));

  //If Statement that creates ripples 
  if (mouseIsPressed && lake < 300) {
    if (mouseY >= 200) {
      noFill();
      stroke('#3895d3');
      strokeWeight(4);
      circle(mouseX, mouseY, ripple);
      ripple = ripple + 5;
      console.log('lake rippling');
      if (ripple >= stoprip) {
        ripple = 10
      }
    } else {
      ripple = 10
    }
  } else if (mouseIsPressed && sun <=35) {
    fill('#fee12b');
    circle(starx, stary, 10);
    console.log('stars');
  }
  background(50, 0.25);
  //For loop that creates the smoke effect with an increasement
  for (let i = 0; i < bugs.length; i++) {
    bugs[i].show();
    bugs[i].move();
    
    if( bugs[i].radius > 100 ) {
      bugs.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  let x = 200;
  let y = 300;
  let rad = random(10, 50);
  let b = new Bug(x, y, rad);
    bugs.push(b);
}

//Particles for evaporation
class Bug {
  constructor(tempX, tempY, tempRadius) {
    this.x = tempX;
    this.y = tempY;
    this.radius = tempRadius;
    this.color = color(random(80,100), 0.05);
  }
//Creates the sketch for it
  show() {
    noStroke();
    fill(this.color);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.radius);
  }
//Moves it up at a random pace
  move() {
    this.x = this.x + random(-5, 5);
    this.y = this.y - random(2);
    this.radius = this.radius + 0.4;
  }
}


function condensation() {
  //Changes the canvas from 400,400 to 600,600
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  //Changes background to grey to imitate storm,
  background(50);
  console.log("CONDENSATION");
  //Colors the cloud and fills it with white
  noStroke();
  fill(255);
  
  //States where cloud spawns
  cloud(xpos,50,1);
  cloud(xpos,50,2);
  cloud(xpos,80,0.75);
  
  xpos++;
  //Has cloud with an increasement
  if (xpos>600) {
    xpos=0;
  }
}

function presipitation() {
 createCanvas(600, 600);
  ellipseMode(RADIUS);
  noFill();
  background(211, 69, 93);
  console.log("PRESIPITATION")

  //If statement that create a for loop that spawns new particles(rain)
  if (particles.length < 200) particles.push(new Particle());
  for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
    particles[i].update();
    particles[i].display();
  }
  
}
var particles = [];
//Variable


//Rain drop / Particle
class Particle {
  
  constructor() {
    this.reset();
  }
  //Resets Particle after update
  reset() {
    this.x = random(width);
    this.y = random(-150, 0);
    this.vy = random(0.1, 2);
    this.maxy = this.y + height;
    this.r = 0;
    this.tr = 50;
    this.w = random(0.1, 2);
  }
  //If statement that creates the gravity for the particle
  update() {
    if (this.y < this.maxy) {
      this.y += this.vy;
    } else {
      this.r++;
    }
    if (this.r > this.tr) this.reset();
  }
  //If statement(says it will remain the raindrop form or change into the puddle
  display() {
    strokeWeight(this.w);
    if (this.y < this.maxy) {
     stroke(255);
     push();
     translate(this.x,this.y);
     beginShape();
     strokeWeight(1);
     vertex(0,-5);
     quadraticVertex(3, 0, 0, 1);
     quadraticVertex(-3,0, 0, -5);
     endShape(CLOSE);
     pop();
    } else {
      stroke(255, map(this.r, 0, this.tr, 255, 0));
      ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r, this.r*.5);
    }
  }
}

//Changes Screen from evaporation, condensation, precipitation
function mousePressed(){
    if(screen==0){
    screen=1;
  }else if(screen==1){
    screen = 2;
  } else if(screen == 2) {
    screen = 0;
  }
}

//Makes cloud
function cloud(x,y,sc){
  push()
  scale(sc);
  ellipse(x,y,50,30);
  ellipse(x,y+20,80,30);
  ellipse(x+20,y,40,30);
  ellipse(x+30,y+10,70,40);
  pop()
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Sketch</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <script src="libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for [createCanvas](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createCanvas):

> Creates a canvas element in the document, and sets the dimensions of it in pixels. This method should be called only once at the start of setup. *Calling createCanvas more than once in a sketch will result in very unpredictable behavior.*

Instead of calling createCanvas repeatedly in your drawing functions, you should use resizeCanvas once when transitioning from one screen to another.

I couldn't actually reproduce whatever issue you were describing (partly because I could not make sense of your description). However I did also notice an issue with the variable `ripple` not being declared anywhere, so I fixed that, and now the sketch appears to be working correctly.

```js
//Variables
let previousScreen = 0;
let screen = 0;
let bugs = [];
let amt = 1000;
let xpos = 0;
let ripple = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  
  colorMode(HSB);
  //Changes Colormode to HSB(Hue-Saturation-Brightness)

  //Creates the particles for the evaporation screen
  //For loop with increasement that states more of the smoke is created
  for (let i = 0; i < amt; i++) {
    let x = 200;
    let y = 300;
    let rad = random(10, 50);

    let b = new Bug(x, y, rad);
    bugs[i] = b;
  }
}

//Says if the value of screen changes so does the screen
function draw() {
  if (screen == 0) {
    if (previousScreen !== screen) {
      resizeCanvas(400, 400);
      previousScreen = screen;
    }
    evaporationscreen();
  } else if (screen == 1) {
    if (previousScreen !== screen) {
      resizeCanvas(600, 600);
      previousScreen = screen;
    }
    condensation();
  } else if (screen == 2) {
    if (previousScreen !== screen) {
      resizeCanvas(600, 600);
      previousScreen = screen;
    }
    
    presipitation();
  }
}

//Evaporation
function evaporationscreen() {
  background('#d2b48c');
  //NOT RGB, HSB COLOR PALLETE(DO NOT MIX UP);

  //HTML Color pallete('e928320');

  noStroke();
  fill('#3895d3') //Lake
  circle(400, 400, 600)
  fill('#18bdf0') //Sky
  rect(0, 0, 400, 200);
  fill('#ffff00'); //Sun
  circle(300, 60, 70);
  fill('#e9bd15'); //Darkspots on Sun
  circle(315, 75, 10); //Forms the Sun and Darkspots
  circle(280, 52, 8); //Forms the Sun and Darkspots
  circle(299, 60, 13); //Forms the Sun and Darkspots
  circle(320, 48, 9); //Forms the Sun and Darkspots
  circle(295, 30, 6); //Forms the Sun and Darkspots
  circle(284, 79, 9); //Forms the Sun and Darkspots
  fill(240, 100, 50); //Forms the Sun and Darkspots
  rect(0, 200, 400, 400); //Beach

  console.log("EVAPORATION");

  //Lots of variables
  let stoprip = 45;
  let lake = int(dist(400, 400, mouseX, mouseY));
  var starx = random(0, 400);
  var stary = random(10, 190);
  var sun = int(dist(300, 60, mouseX, mouseY));

  //If Statement that creates ripples 
  if (mouseIsPressed && lake < 300) {
    if (mouseY >= 200) {
      noFill();
      stroke('#3895d3');
      strokeWeight(4);
      circle(mouseX, mouseY, ripple);
      ripple = ripple + 5;
      console.log('lake rippling');
      if (ripple >= stoprip) {
        ripple = 10
      }
    } else {
      ripple = 10
    }
  } else if (mouseIsPressed && sun <= 35) {
    fill('#fee12b');
    circle(starx, stary, 10);
    console.log('stars');
  }
  background(50, 0.25);
  //For loop that creates the smoke effect with an increasement
  for (let i = 0; i < bugs.length; i++) {
    bugs[i].show();
    bugs[i].move();

    if (bugs[i].radius > 100) {
      bugs.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  let x = 200;
  let y = 300;
  let rad = random(10, 50);
  let b = new Bug(x, y, rad);
  bugs.push(b);
}

//Particles for evaporation
class Bug {
  constructor(tempX, tempY, tempRadius) {
    this.x = tempX;
    this.y = tempY;
    this.radius = tempRadius;
    this.color = color(random(80, 100), 0.05);
  }
  //Creates the sketch for it
  show() {
    noStroke();
    fill(this.color);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.radius);
  }
  //Moves it up at a random pace
  move() {
    this.x = this.x + random(-5, 5);
    this.y = this.y - random(2);
    this.radius = this.radius + 0.4;
  }
}


function condensation() {
  //Changes background to grey to imitate storm,
  background(50);
  console.log("CONDENSATION");
  //Colors the cloud and fills it with white
  noStroke();
  fill(255);

  //States where cloud spawns
  cloud(xpos, 50, 1);
  cloud(xpos, 50, 2);
  cloud(xpos, 80, 0.75);

  xpos++;
  //Has cloud with an increasement
  if (xpos > 600) {
    xpos = 0;
  }
}

function presipitation() {
  ellipseMode(RADIUS);
  noFill();
  background(211, 69, 93);
  console.log("PRESIPITATION")

  //If statement that create a for loop that spawns new particles(rain)
  if (particles.length < 200) particles.push(new Particle());
  for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
    particles[i].update();
    particles[i].display();
  }

}
var particles = [];
//Variable


//Rain drop / Particle
class Particle {

  constructor() {
    this.reset();
  }
  //Resets Particle after update
  reset() {
    this.x = random(width);
    this.y = random(-150, 0);
    this.vy = random(0.1, 2);
    this.maxy = this.y + height;
    this.r = 0;
    this.tr = 50;
    this.w = random(0.1, 2);
  }
  //If statement that creates the gravity for the particle
  update() {
    if (this.y < this.maxy) {
      this.y += this.vy;
    } else {
      this.r++;
    }
    if (this.r > this.tr) this.reset();
  }
  
  //If statement(says it will remain the raindrop form or change into the puddle
  display() {
    strokeWeight(this.w);
    if (this.y < this.maxy) {
      stroke(255);
      push();
      translate(this.x, this.y);
      beginShape();
      strokeWeight(1);
      vertex(0, -5);
      quadraticVertex(3, 0, 0, 1);
      quadraticVertex(-3, 0, 0, -5);
      endShape(CLOSE);
      pop();
    } else {
      stroke(255, map(this.r, 0, this.tr, 255, 0));
      ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r, this.r * .5);
    }
  }
}

//Changes Screen from evaporation, condensation, precipitation
function mousePressed() {
  if (screen == 0) {
    screen = 1;
  } else if (screen == 1) {
    screen = 2;
  } else if (screen == 2) {
    screen = 0;
  }
}

//Makes cloud
function cloud(x, y, sc) {
  push();
  scale(sc);
  ellipse(x, y, 50, 30);
  ellipse(x, y + 20, 80, 30);
  ellipse(x + 20, y, 40, 30);
  ellipse(x + 30, y + 10, 70, 40);
  pop();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```